# How to implement mode-k product Python for Tacker decomposition?

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

I am trying to do Tacker decomposition in python.
I refer [this page](https://www.alexejgossmann.com/tensor_decomposition_tucker/).

I would like to implement mode-k product in Python using NumPy. According to the above web page, I have to do mode-k product.

I write mode3 product. But I think there are more good ways to calculate them.

```
l1 = 3
l2 = 3
l3 = 3
l4 = 3
J = 2
X = np.random.uniform(0,1,(l1,l2,l3,l4))
M = np.random.uniform(0,1,(J,l3))

def mode_3_prodcut(X,M,mode=3):
    A = np.zeros((l1,l2,J,l4))
    for i1 in range(l1):
        for i2 in range(l2):
            for j in range(J):
                for i4 in range(l4):
                    term = 0
                    for i3 in range(l3):
                        term += X[i1,i2,i3,i4] * M[j,i3]

                    A[i1,i2,j,i4] = term

    return A
```

**EDIT**

I write define of mode-k product between tensor X ∈ R^{l_1×l_2×…×l_N} and matrix M ∈ R^{J×l_n}.

l_1,l_2,…,l_N are natural numbers. Mode-k product between X and M is given as X ⊗_n M,

> ( X ⊗_n M ) ∈ R^{l_1×l_2×…×l_(n-1)×J×l_(n+1)×…×l_N}
>
> ( X ⊗_n M )*{i_1,…,i*{n-1},j,i_{n+1},…,i_N} = Σ_{i_n}^{l_n} X_{i_1,…,i_{n-1},i_n,i_{n+1},…,i_N} m_{j,i_n}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer.

```
def mode_n_product(x, m, mode):
   x = np.asarray(x)
   m = np.asarray(m)
   if mode <= 0 or mode % 1 != 0:
       raise ValueError('`mode` must be a positive interger')
   if x.ndim < mode:
       raise ValueError('Invalid shape of X for mode = {}: {}'.format(mode, x.shape))
   if m.ndim != 2:
       raise ValueError('Invalid shape of M: {}'.format(m.shape))
   return np.swapaxes(np.swapaxes(x, mode - 1, -1).dot(m.T), mode - 1, -1)
```